# Python - Can't scrape data from a specific website (CourseHero)

Tags: python, web-scraping

I've recently wanted to started a bot project that interacts with the website (https://www.coursehero.com/) using Python.
But.. it looks like that website has a high anti-bot security system, that returns a false html data when attempting to log in, so I guess the only possible way is to log in as a fake human interface.

> I'm in a study group, and the entire idea of the bot is to let the
> participants download doc files from my premium account on that
> website without having to give them the login information.

I'm already very good at Python, but new to webscraping.

**Any help?**

Comment: Use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html), it emulates human user

Comment: Course Hero front-end sends POST request to `https://www.coursehero.com/api/v2/search` and renders search results from JavaScript. Try sending a similar HTTP request from Python instead of fetching HTML and parse JSON response. Also, send browser-like user agents and use proxies to receive proper HTML response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Course Hero front-end sends POST request to `https://www.coursehero.com/api/v2/search` and renders search results from JavaScript.

[image: POST response preview]

Just fetch JSON via an HTTP request. [Full example](https://repl.it/@ilyazub/scrape-coursehero-python). I don't have a paid account so the last part of the code is commented since it's a pseudo-code.

```py
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent':
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.3987.78 Safari/537.36'
}

data = {
    "client": "web",
    "query": "scrape",
    "view": "list_w",
    "filters": {
        "type": ["document"],
        "doc_type": [],
    },
    "sort": "relevancy",
    "limit": 20,
    "offset": 0,
    "callout_types": ["textbook"]
}

response = requests.post(
    'https://www.coursehero.com/api/v2/search/', headers=headers, json=data)

data = response.json()

for result in data['results']:
    url = f"https://www.coursehero.com/file/{result['document']['db_filename']}"
    print(f"'{result['core']['title']}' URL: {url}")

    # Login and extract download URL from HTML
    #
    # response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    # soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
    # download_url = soup.select('...')
    #
    # OR
    #
    # Download file via direct HTTP request if URL is returned via XHR request
    #
    # download_url = 'https://www.coursehero.com/...'
    # requests.get(download_url, headers=headers)
```

Output

```
'Week 6 - Web Scraping.pptx' URL: https://www.coursehero.com/file/38748386
'Python web_scraping train.docx' URL: https://www.coursehero.com/file/70193727
'ScrAPES Book' URL: https://www.coursehero.com/file/6219095
'scrape.py' URL: https://www.coursehero.com/file/43396377
'scrAPES - Rain didn't Boost Lakes' URL: https://www.coursehero.com/file/10042922
'orders cannot scrape.docx' URL: https://www.coursehero.com/file/75016027

...
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, your method worked for a while.. but suddenly it started returning the same false data again..
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qnfke32c8sl0frz/

Comment: @Shizuka Try rotating user agent strings via [`fake-useragent`](https://pypi.org/project/fake-useragent) and use multiple proxies to avoid being blocked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to interact with the website. But I am currently scraping sites (include Google, Wikipedia, Quora,...) by using a proxy provider, such as ScraperAPI.

**Advantages:**

- Thoundsand of proxies over the world.
- High success rate.
- 1000 requests per month for free plan.

**Disadvantages:**

- Request time is quite long.
- Some request could be failed, and need to request again several time.